# redis.exceptions.LockError: Cannot release an unlocked lock after restarting celerybeat

Tags: django, redis, celery, django-celery

sometimes after restarting celerybeat , I get the following error, I have setup celerybeat as a service with redis,

```
sude service celerybeat restart
```

Below is the exception trace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/pyenv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 484, in start
    time.sleep(interval)
  File "/home/ec2-user/pyenv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/apps/beat.py", line 148, in _sync
    beat.sync()
  File "/home/ec2-user/pyenv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 493, in sync
    self.scheduler.close()
  File "/home/ec2-user/pyenv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/redbeat/schedulers.py", line 272, in close
    self.lock.release()
  File "/home/ec2-user/pyenv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/redis/lock.py", line 135, in release
    self.do_release(expected_token)
  File "/home/ec2-user/pyenv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/redis/lock.py", line 264, in do_release
    raise LockError("Cannot release a lock that's no longer owned")
redis.exceptions.LockError: Cannot release a lock that's no longer owned

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/pyenv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/apps/beat.py", line 112, in start_scheduler
    beat.start()
  File "/home/ec2-user/pyenv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 490, in start
    self.sync()
  File "/home/ec2-user/pyenv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 493, in sync
    self.scheduler.close()
  File "/home/ec2-user/pyenv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/redbeat/schedulers.py", line 272, in close
    self.lock.release()
  File "/home/ec2-user/pyenv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/redis/lock.py", line 133, in release
    raise LockError("Cannot release an unlocked lock")
redis.exceptions.LockError: Cannot release an unlocked lock
```

The exception does not happen every time and I have not noticed any issues caused by this, celerybeat works fine even after this exception. Since it is the production environment, I want to handle it safely.

Answer (score 5):

I have noticed the same in my logs, for me the reason was the redis timeout was shorter than the task took, so it tried to release a lock after it expired, for example:

```
with redis_client.lock('some_key', timeout=5):
    time.sleep(10)
```

which gives

> redis.exceptions.LockError: Cannot release a lock that's no longer
>   owned

Comment: This turned out to be the same reason we were getting this error in our app as well. 

We ended up writing a wrapper around that `with` block to catch the exception.

Then, we would check if the contents of the `with` block have been executed successfully. If everything went OK, the exception would stay silenced, if not, we would re-raise.

Comment: Any sample of that code?